# Python subprocess yielding a different result than shell?

Tags: python, git, shell

I'm trying to run a git log command from a python script to find how much one branch has diverged from another (i.e. how many commits). The git command I'm using is this:

```
git log HEAD ^master --no-merges --oneline | wc -l
```

From what I understand, I should be able to run this in python using subprocess, like so:

```
import subprocess;
print subprocess.check_output('git log HEAD ^master --no-merges --oneline | wc -l',  shell=True)
```

However, I am consistently getting different results from these two pieces of code.

To test this, I created a new branch off of master, modified a file, and committed it. Then I ran my two commands:

```
$ git log HEAD ^master --no-merges --oneline | wc -l
    1

$ python -c "import subprocess; print subprocess.check_output('git log HEAD ^master --no-merges --oneline | wc -l', shell=True)"
    1334
```

Any idea why this might be the case? Am I just crazy?

**UPDATE:**

I've been able to work around this by using the strategy mentioned in the subprocess docs:

```
command = ['git', 'log', 'HEAD', '^master', '--no-merges', '--oneline']
p1 = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
commit_count = int(p2.communicate()[0])
```

I'm still curious, though, why the shell=True strategy yields such different results...

Comment: I guess you have to specify your pipes seperately, as subprocess escapes  `|`.

Comment: @ch3ka Nope, with `shell=True`, it just passes the line to the default shell.

Comment: Can you dump the output of the command without `wc -l`? I think the culprit is `shell=True` since the shell that is invoked for running your command is different from the one you use.

Comment: What is the output if you don't pipe to `wc -l` for the python case?

Comment: Seems to still be running the same command. Prints out a thousand lines of git log....

Comment: I have the same problem too with PHP. Running the command as a shell returns different results than by simply running the git process. I'm currently working on finding the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be the two invocations have different environments? Like, different current dirs?

Try this without `| wc -l` and/or with diagnostic flags to have a better understanding of what exactly gets done.

Comment: Yeah, that occurred to me, too. Setting the `cwd` param didn't seem to help :/

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what it's doing, as there's just so many lines.... I can at least tell that it doesn't output all commits in the repo (`git rev-list HEAD --count` returns a different value than the python function).

Comment: Eh... pipe to file and see with `less`/`head`? Looks like a different command is being executed.